# JavaScript REGEX: give me everything except what is between this pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable that contains the entire html for a page as a string value:

```
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="foo.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- MY PANEL -->

            <div id="edit-area"></div>

            <div id="my-panel">
                <ul class="menu menu-top">
                    <li>a</li>
                    <li>b</li>
                    <li>c</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="menu menu-bottom">
                    <li>a</li>
                </ul>
                <pre id="code" contenteditable="true"></pre>
            </div>

            <!-- END MY PANEL -->

            <div id="original-content">

                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 100px"></div>

            </div>


        </div>

</body></html>
```

I need to change this value to everything except what's in between the comments. I need just this:

```
<html><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="foo.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">


            <div id="original-content">

                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 100px"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

</body></html>
```

I tried this:

```
var regex = /<!-- MY PANEL -->.+?<!-- END MY PANEL -->/;
alert(my_variable.replace(regex, ''));
```

But it just alerts the entire value with the stuff in between the comments intact and not removed.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = subject.replace(/<!-- MY PANEL -->[\s\S]+?<!-- END MY PANEL -->/g, "");
```

Let us know if you need some more help

Comment: this replaces both opening and closing comments with an empty string, it still keeps all the stuff within it. I would like not just the opening and closing comments to be removed but also all the content within it's bounds.

Comment: As Kevin said, the \s\S is a dirty trick that javascript forces on you

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not match newlines, and JavaScript doesn't have a "dotall" option like PHP does.

To get around this, use a character class that completes itself, such as `[\d\D]` to mean "any digit or any non-digit", instead of `.`.

Result: `regex = /<!-- MY PANEL -->[\d\D]+?<!-- END MY PANEL -->/;`

Answer (score 0):

`.` will never match line breaks. You must use some other pattern which matches everything, such as `(.|[\r\n])*?` or `[\s\S]*?`.

Answer (score 0):

according to this regExr (http://regexr.com?30dpi), this works:

```
<!-- MY PANEL -->(\s*.*?)*<!-- END MY PANEL -->
```

but as it is with regexes, this is probably not the sweetest.